# Update child span content looping through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below HTML content where I would like to update HTML of all the span from XYZ to ABC.

```
var HTML = '<div>Testing</div><span>XYZ<a href="#">Link Data</a></span><div>This is content</div><span>XYZ</span>';
```

I have tried by below code but seems to be main HTML content is updating by this or replace works well but main content is not updating by that,

```
$.each($(HTML).find("> span"), function(index) {  
  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace('XYZ', ''ABC'');
});
```

Any inputs?

Comment: You can just use `$('span').text('ABC')`

Comment: Are you trying to change *all* the `span` elements, or only those that contain `XYZ`?

Comment: I have updated question, HTML not in the DOM but it's an variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the logic in your current JS code, you only want to affect the `span` elements that have the `XYZ` value in their text, not all of them.

To do that you can provide a function to `html()` which you can use to update the current value. Try this:

```js
var html = '<div>Testing</div><span>XYZ<a href="#">Link Data</a></span><div>This is content</div><span>XYZ</span>'; 

$(html).filter('span').html(function(i, h) {
  return h.replace('XYZ', 'ABC');
}).end().appendTo('div');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

If you want to amend the string value only, then you can amend the above to work within an element in memory and then return the content from that, like this:

```js
var html = '<div>Testing</div><span>XYZ<a href="#">Link Data</a></span><div>This is content</div><span>XYZ</span>'; 

html = $('<div>' + html + '</div>').find('span').html(function(i, h) {
  return h.replace('XYZ', 'ABC');
}).end().html();

console.log(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I have updated question, HTML not in the DOM but it's an variable.

Comment: That affects the logic you use to retrieve the `span` elements slightly. I updated the answer for you

Comment: Does ".appendTo('div')"  is required? because here span is fixed but parent element can be div or any other.

Comment: That's only to show the output in the demo. It's not required.

Comment: Let me try. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Rory, Referring to example of JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pzmupwea/ after replace, main HTML string which is in the JS variable should update, it should not append to the another element. If you check fiddle example then html alert still holds the old value. Any input on how JS variable gets updated by replaced string?

Comment: That's because the code updates the DOM only, not the string. If you want to update the string, you could retrieve the `html()` from the `div` that was updated: https://jsfiddle.net/pzmupwea/1/

Comment: Thanks for reply, but we do not have such external elements in our case, so without having external element like div in this case, can we update string directly?

Comment: In your example in the question you're appending the string to the innerHTML of a `span`...

Comment: I know, that was my total wrong attempt. Now, the issue which I am facing is, the JS variable which holds the HTML should update based on the replace without having any external element. Any inputs will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Rory, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood you want to replace the text of all the  spans that their content is `XYZ` so you can write:

```js
$('span').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() === "XYZ") {
    $(this).text("ABC");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>Testing</div>
  <span>XYZ</span>
  <div>This is content</div>
  <span>XYZ</span>
  <p><span>XZZ</span></p>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**

If your HTML is in a variable you can create a new HTML element and put your HTML on it and use the same code.

And in case where the  spans contains also HTML code use `string.prototype.replace()` method to do the trick, here's the updated fiddle:

```js
var htmlCode = '<div>Testing</div><span>XYZ</span><div>This is content</div><span>XYZ</span><p><span>XZZ</span></p>';

var div = $('<div></div>');
div.html(htmlCode);
div.find('span').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().match("XYZ") != null) {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/XYZ/, "ABC"));
  }
});

console.log(div.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have updated question, HTML not in the DOM but it's an variable.

Comment: Here span has text plus HTML so text method won't work here.

Comment: @AnkitShah I updated my answer with a working snippet, but you should mentioned that in the first place, because it only appears in your last edit.

Answer (score 0):

***Updated answer*** .use with `Contains()` function of jquery it will find the `XYZ` text in span and replace with `ABC` and unchanged the children data

```js
var HTML = '<div>Testing</div><span>XYZ<a href="#">Link Data</a></span><div> This is content </div><span> XYZ </span>';
$('body').append(HTML);
$('span:Contains("XYZ")').each(function(){
var a = $(this).children().html() ? $(this).children().html() :"";
  $(this).html('ABC'+a);
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have updated question, HTML not in the DOM but it's an variable.

Comment: Here span has text plus HTML so text method won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
<script>
    $.each($('html').find("> span"), function(index) {  
     if($(this).text() == "XYZ") 
        $(this).html('ABC');
});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will replace span text from "XYZ" to "ABC"

```js
var html = '<div>Testing</div><span>XYZ</span><div>This is content</div><span>XYZ</span>';

var htmlObj = $(html);
htmlObj.filter('span').each(function() {
  if($(this).text() == "XYZ") {
    $(this).text("ABC") 
  }
});

var htmlString = $('<div>').append(htmlObj).html();
console.log(htmlString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have updated question, HTML not in the DOM but it's an variable.

Comment: Here span has text plus HTML so text method won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var compare = "XYZ";
$("span").filter(function() {

  return $(this).text() == compare;

}).text("ABC")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Testing</div>
<span>XYZ</span>
<div>This is content</div>
<span>XYZ</span>
```

You can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

Comment: I have updated question, HTML not in the DOM but it's an variable.

Comment: Here span has text plus HTML so text method won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

For example this snippet is working for me:

```
$.each($('span'), function () {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace('XYZ', 'ABC')
})
```

Is this what you're looking for or maybe you need an IIFE to be called on document load to replace the content from the page after it's available.